# Mobile menu popup not scrolling when sliding up and down

Tags: ios, html, windows-phone-7, mobile

I have a menu that I popup from the bottom which is actually a tree view style control. I was thinking that the mobile phone would recognize that the new Div element is the top most element and with the menu content being bigger in height than the phone I thought you'd be able to be able to slide the menu up and down. 
It seems however that the mobile phone (iOS and Windows Phone) keep scrolling the content behind the Div as though it isn't there.

The code is very simple, it's just a Div element in the root of the Dom with a z-index set as well as position absolute.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed to resolve this is to put the mobile menu in the root alongside the main content DIV. Then, when the mobile menu button is clicked I set the main content DIV display property to None and the Mobile Menu DIV to Block.

Essentially I'm hiding the site content and showing the menu content and vice versa.

This allows you to scroll the menu as though it's normal content.